# Somar varios selects

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Como faço para somar o resultado de vários selects, por exemplo, eu tenho 2 selects que cada um deles traz um campo de valor, ou seja, com a soma de algo...

Select 1:

```
 SELECT SUM(ms.valor) as valor
 FROM risco1.margem_solicitada ms
 WHERE ms.codigo = 5410477
 AND ms.data= '26/05/2020'
```

Select 2:

```
 SELECT SUM(mbmf.valor - mbmf.valor_sacado) as valor
 FROM risco1.margem_solicitada2 mbmf
 WHERE mbmf.codigo = 5410477
 AND mbmf.data= '26/05/2020'
```

Como somo o resultado desses 2 selects ? ja vi que só colocando um '+' entre eles nao funciona...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz uma subquery com os 2 selects (pode usar `union` para junta-los), e depois soma a partir dessa soma:

```
WITH totais AS(
SELECT SUM(ms.valor) as valor
 FROM risco1.margem_solicitada ms
 WHERE ms.codigo = 5410477
 AND ms.data= '26/05/2020'

UNION

SELECT SUM(mbmf.valor - mbmf.valor_sacado) as valor
 FROM risco1.margem_solicitada2 mbmf
 WHERE mbmf.codigo = 5410477
 AND mbmf.data= '26/05/2020'
)
select sum(valor) as totalfinal from totais
```

Para manipular as subqueries, usei o `WITH`, que nomeia o resultado para "totais", como se fosse uma tabela

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Sempre que for usar uma union certifique das colunas terem o mesmo nome. Após usar o union, você pode criar um view. E em outra você agrupa e conta. Como não tenho muita experiencia sempre uso esse recurso.