# sum em duas tabelas numa única consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Tenha duas consultas, uma em cada tabela.

```
select SUM(quantidade) as total1 FROM tbmateria GROUP by codigomateria
select SUM(quantidade) as total2 FROM tbmateriaestoque GROUP by codigomateria
```

preciso fazer (total2 - total1), mas tem que ser uma única query.

tentei fazer assim, mas sem sucesso

```
SELECT
(SUM(tbmateria.quantidade) - SUM(tbmateriaestoque.quantidade)) as soma4,tbmateria.nomemateria
```

FROM
    tbmateria
INNER JOIN tbmateriaestoque ON(tbmateria.codigomateria = tbmateriaestoque.codigomateria)

GROUP BY
    tbmateria.codigomateria

Comment: veja se isso responde sua pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/454569/57220

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "sem sucesso"? Deu erro? O resultado não foi o esperado?

Comment: os cálculos estão errados. aparece um números muito altos, por ex: 1537406.250

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá,

Veja se resolve, mas tem alguns problemas de validação ainda! Se não existir o resgitro do codigomateria nas 2 tabelas!

```
SELECT 

t.codigomateria, 
(
(SELECT SUM(tte.quantidade) FROM tbmateriaestoque tte WHERE tte.codigomateria = t.codigomateria GROUP BY tte.codigomateria)
-
(SELECT SUM(tt.quantidade) FROM tbmateria tt WHERE tt.codigomateria = t.codigomateria  GROUP BY tt.codigomateria)
) AS diferenca

FROM tbmateria t 
JOIN tbmateriaestoque te ON (t.codigomateria = te.codigomateria)
GROUP BY t.codigomateria
```

Neste caso, iria fazer trazer todos codigos... para filtrar, adicione um WHERE no final!

Não consegui testar... mas acho que vai dar certo!

Comment: Perfeito duda, só precisei colocar GROUP BY t.codigomateria no final. muito obrigado.

Comment: Acho que isso seria necessário se t.codigomateria não for UNIQUEKEY... mas beleza, vou atualizar a resposta!